# Passing data to fragment via Bundle OR a public method defined inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

Can anyone tell what will be the difference between following approaches for sharing data to fragment.

- Using Bundle.

  ```
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
      args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
      fragment.setArguments(args);
  ```
- Using a public method defined inside fragment.

  ```
  MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
  fragment.setData("param");


  public void setData(String param1) {
          this.param1 = param1;
      }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

The `Bundle` is built in and supported by the framework.  If the `Fragment` is automatically torn down and re-created by the framework due to lifecycle you will still get the `Bundle` back.

In the second case, the private data member `param1` won't be automatically re-created by the framework if the `Fragment` is torn down and re-created.  It's the same reason you don't use overloaded constructors with `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Bundle` if you want to provide data to a `fragment`, but want to decide inside the `fragment` when to use this data.

Use a method call if you want to pass data to an already active `fragment` and expect instant reaction from the `fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to have an instance of the  class from which you want to access the data.
This may leads to memory leaks
If you use public methods frequently instead of bundle ,
Via bundle you can share data without any reference via android message mechanism